I can't find vertex after Single vert
HI I found how to use this add on from youtuber “Keelan Jon”
He shown the tutorial which look like easy and intereting,
I try to following as his step as below
Blender Character Modeling Tutorial - Stylised Character Tutorial - Blender Tutorial - YouTube 7
Min 1:30 to 3:00
Add single vert> add modifier skin> but I stucked when the single vert was not shown the all vertices. It shown only 1 or 2 as following core of if instead of vertices all each edge.
Please tell me how to fix it or the way to be as on the clip.

this is mine...
and this is what I want to be..


Hi :)  Before selecting the single vertex and extruding upwards you first have to "jump into X ray mode  using the  Alt+Z  shortcut keys". He states that at 2min 04 seconds in the video.

Before selecting the single vertex and extruding upwards you first have to "jump into X-Ray mode  using the Alt+Z shortcut keys". He states that at 2min 04 seconds in the video.
X-Ray mode enables you to select the single vertex at the centre which is hidden by the geometry created by the modifiers.
An alternative to using Alt+Z you can enable X-Ray mode by activating the little XRay button in the viewport header, top right. see screenshot below.

